# How to configure staging env on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails app on Heroku using the Postgres 9 beta.

I've tried to configure a staging environment using

`heroku config:add RACK_ENV=staging --remote staging`

but the app still thinks its in a production env.

```
Rails.env
=>"production"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Did you add RAILS_ENV=staging too ?